# Counting the sum of every nodes' neighbors' degrees?

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

For each node u in an undirected graph, let twodegree[u] be the sum of the degrees of u's neighbors. Show how to compute the entire array of twodegree[.] values in linear time, given a graph in adjacency list format.

This is the solution

```
for all u ∈  V :
  degree[u] = 0
  for all (u; w) ∈  E:
    degree[u] = degree[u] + 1
for all u ∈  V :
  twodegree[u] = 0
  for all (u; w) ∈  E:
    twodegree[u] = twodegree[u] + degree[w]
```

can someone explain what degree[u] does in this case and how twodegree[u] = twodegree[u] + degree[w] is supposed to be the sum of the degrees of u's neighbors?

Answer (score 4):

Here, `degree[u]` is the degree of the node `u` (that is, the number of nodes adjacent to it). You can see this computed by the first loop, which iterates over all edges in the graph and increments `degree[u]` for each edge in the graph.

The second loop then iterates over every node in the graph and computes the sum of all its neighbors' degrees. It uses the fact that `degree[u]` is precomputed in order to run in O(m + n) time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you explain how this is O(n + m)? there is two for loops one inside the other. how is it linear time and not O(nm)?

Comment: @SharhadBashar You can conservatively bound the runtime at O(mn) by multiplying the number of iterations of the outer loop by the maximum number of iterations of the inner loop, but that bound won’t be tight. Rather than proceeding that way, instead think about how many total times that inner loop runs across all iterations of the outer loop. There are only m total edges in the graph, so that inner loop, across all iterations, can only run O(m) total times. So the work done here is O(m) for the edges plus O(n) for all the other work, for the total of O(m + n).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @templatetypedef has said, the statement `twodegree[u] = twodegree[u] + degree[w]` simply keeps track of the twodegree of `u` while it keeps iteratively (or cumulatively) adding the degrees of its neighbors (that are temporarily stored in `w`)